# create Haxe projects in FDT 5.5

Tags: haxe, fdt

I have download FDT 5.5 free version to test for Haxe projects.
but when I create FDT project I just see Web,AIR and plugin **not Haxe project** .
does anyone can help me to figure it out.
I surfed flash developer  FAQ website and did not find anything and tutorial is jsut for FDT 5 Version

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is something wrong with your installation. Clicking *File*, *New*, *New FDT Project* should give you an option to create a new Haxe project:

[image: New Haxe project with FDT]